# How to set QGIS map canvas size programmatically

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, extents, mapcanvas

I need my map canvas to be exactly 1920x1080. So the `Save as image` would save a png exactly this size.
I've tried setting it with

`iface.mapCanvas.resize(QSize(1920,1080))`

But no luck, `resize()` seems to be deprecated.
I'm using QGIS 2.16.0.

I'd also like to set map extent programmatically, if that's related.
Unfortunately, using composer is not an option here.

Comment: I find the saved image is 2 pixels smaller in height and width than the size set with `.resize()` - QGIS 2.14 (maybe fixed in 2.16?).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the following to resize the map canvas:

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import QSize
iface.mapCanvas().resize(QSize(1920,1080))
```

You need to import `QSize` before being able to use it. Although you seem to be correct in that it was [depreciated](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsMapCanvasMap.html#a9c7332bfe7179a1f07dc6d872c8d9255).